# TypeError: a is null only with Google maps code

Tags: javascript, typeerror

Javascrip/jQuery noob here. I have created a google map successfully on an external file. I have moved that code into my website and it will not run, throwing the following map-breaking error in Firebug:

"TypeError: a is null" on line #44 of main.js which is a google maps js file and not one of mine.

The gmap code that I am using inside the head tag is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
          var map;
          var centerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(33.460658, -79.182048);
          var zoomLevel = 8;
          function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
              center: centerPos,
              zoom: zoomLevel
            };
            map = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById("#map-canvas"), mapOptions );
            var locations = [
              ['3650 Claypond Rd, Myrtle Beach, SC 29579', 33.716628, -78.941253],
              ['1530 Highmarket St, Georgetown, SC 29440', 33.375282, -79.290767]
            ];

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) { 
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        title: locations[i][0],
        map: map
      });
    }
          }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

I have correctly named the map's target div id "map-canvas", I have placed alerts through the above code using them like trace statements and know that the code above is loading.

Does anybody have any suggestions? Anything jump out at you? After 4 hours of research I can't get it to budge for me. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you attempt to make a minimal working example? That is, use http://jsfiddle.net/ to show us not only the JS you include here but also the HTML.

Comment: Try to minimize. Do you get the error if you don't add the markers?

Comment: @stark - Thanks for the quick help. - I removed the locations and the error went away. Now I have half of what I need but at least no errors. I had to wimp out chasing down this problem because I have an important, looming deadline so I was able to circumvent the problem by using the GMap3 jquery plugin for Google Maps. It worked perfectly and immediately. I still wanna figure this out, just not today or tomorrow! Thanks!